# Invensense Motion Driver 6.12 STM32 demo python don't work

Tags: python, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I am trying to run the Invensense motion_driver_6.12. I compiled the code with IAR and the STM32 works ok - all the test I've done with the board are ok: UART, I2C.. etc. But when I run the python client demo program "eMPL-client-py" the program shows only one empty black window and nothing occurs. I tried to run first the program and then switch on the board and vice-versa.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I worked with this library for a week almost gave up and today finally I got this image.

[image: python client]

Platform :

**STM32F429ZI** , **STM32-Disc0--MB1075B development kit**

motion_driver_6.12 in IAR

[MPU9250/6050](https://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.16.37a71da6FHTrOt&id=42408784668&cm_id=140105335569ed55e27b&abbucket=2) (not an advertisement,I dont use an official eval-board )

At first ,I even cannot make the python-client work. After reading [this passage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127245/serialwin32-py-and-serialutil-py-error-when-run-invensense-demo-python-client?newreg=4d5d5e4a90a741668d8cc12976b92b76) , I can open the cube window.

Just like you, I only got a empty window. Then I modified the `motion_driver_6.12` making it suitable for my board(ports conflict existing) :

```
1、USART：USART2-->USART1，PA9（TXD）and PA10（RXD）；
2、I2C：I2C2-->I2C3，PA8（SCL）and PC9（SDA）
3、INT:PA1-->PA5（EXTI9_5_IRQn,EXTI9_5_IRQHandler,EXTI_Line5).
```

Make sure everything done before connecting the sensor with your board. Especially the configuration in the ARM project. An useful suggestion is to test every module such as i2c, usart and interruption.

If it's useful , give me a thumb .
Any problem just comment below .

Answer (score -1):

which type of Invensense chip you are using?

1. I think you need to check if you use the right COM Port in windows.
2. Check if you could get data from your MPUxxxx Board through I2C
3. Check `log_stm32.c` if this function work well `fputc(out[i]);`